# Python elasticsearch client returns true when type does not exists

Tags: python, python-2.7, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am trying to delete the mapping of a type but before doing that I am checking if the type exists as in the code below:

```
def delete_mapping(self, doc_type):
    if self.elasticsearch.indices.exists_type(index='my_index', doc_type=doc_type):
        self.elasticsearch.indices.delete_mapping(index='my_index', doc_type=doc_type)
```

The line that checks if the type exists is returning true, even for a non-existing type. So I get TypeMissingException in the next line while trying to delete the mapping of the type.

When we run the code on the ipython console everything looks good, the problem occurs when the code is run as part of an async task. This does not happens every single time but randomly on the QA and Production servers. These two environments are the only ones in which we have two nodes for elasticsearch, we don't see the problem on other environments.

I am working with Python 2.7, elasticsearch-py 0.4.4 and elasticsearch version 1.0.1 with two nodes over a 64bit Linux. The code is run as a periodic celery task.

EDIT: Added more details to the problem.

Comment: From documentation, `index – A comma-separated list of index names;` ... maybe if you pass `my_index` as a list ?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details. I am running the code on iPython and sending a string or list is equally valid, it returns true when the type exists and false when it doesn't. The problem occurs when the code is executed as par of a celery periodic task.

Comment: Instead of trying to check if the type exist before deleting it, have you tried to pass `ignore=[404]` to delete_mapping ?

Comment: Maybe a dumb question, but is your celery task configured to run only on one node or is it installed on both nodes and configured to run at the same time? Maybe you have a race condition there.

Comment: I am going to try the `ignore=[404]` suggestion for now. Will test that on the QA env. Thanks.

Comment: RabbitMQ runs on a single Node. Elasticsearch is the one running on two nodes.

Comment: Not quite sure to the cause of your problem (or if you are seeking that or a solution to it), but I think it could be easily solved by surrounding your code block with a try/except that catches any `TypeMissingException` exceptions.